# A trigonometic integral with complex technicals

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Show that $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a^2\cos^2(t)+b^2\sin^2(t)}dt=\frac{2\pi}{ab}$$ Help please!
Thanks.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565844/principal-value-of-the-singular-integral-int-0-pi-frac-cos-nt-cos-t-co/565862#565862).

Comment: Try the Weierstrass substitution, which turns antiderivatives involving a rational function of sine and cosine into another integral which is a rational function in a new variable. Link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: @coffeemath looking at the questions here, it is quite amazing how few people know of this standard tool.

Comment: This integral was discussed at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518173/calculate-the-integral-int-02-pi-frac1a2-cos2tb2-sin2tdt).

Comment: This question does not ask for a complex integration solution, so the mentioned duplicate (deformation theorem) does not seem to match. Weierstrass substitution seems a better approach for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to conclude what you want:
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \dfrac{dt}{1+r \sin^2(t)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-r)^k \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{2k}(t)dt = 2 \pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-r/4)^k \dbinom{2k}k = \dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1+r}}$$
where we used the fact that
[$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{2k}(t) dt = \dfrac{2\pi}{4^k}\dbinom{2k}k$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/striking-applications-of-integration-by-parts/20481#20481)
and
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+r}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-r/4)^k \dbinom{2k}k$$
We have
$$a^2 \cos^2(t) + b^2 \sin^2(t) = a^2 + (b^2-a^2)\sin^2(t) = a^2\left(1+\left(\left(\dfrac{b}a\right)^2 - 1\right)\sin^2(t)\right)$$
Hence, in our case, we have $r = \left(\dfrac{b}a \right)^2 - 1$ and hence $\sqrt{1+r} = \dfrac{b}a$.
$$I = \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{dt}{a^2 \cos^2(t) + b^2 \sin^2(t)} = \dfrac1{a^2} \times \dfrac{2\pi}{b/a} = \dfrac{2\pi}{ab}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\frac1{a^2\cos^2t+b^2\sin^2t}=\frac1{a^2\cos^2t}\frac1{1+\left(\frac ba\tan t\right)^2}=\frac1{ab}\frac{\left(\frac ba\tan t\right)'}{1+\left(\frac ba\tan t\right)^2}\implies$$

$$\implies\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac1{a^2\cos^2t+b^2\sin^2t}dt=\left.\frac1{ab}\arctan\left(\frac ba\tan t\right)\right|_0^{2\pi}$$

**But** ...observe closely the point $\;\pi/2\;,\;\;3\pi/2\;$...