# Calculating the integral $\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{a^2 \sin^2\theta+b^2 \cos^2\theta}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I wanted to calculate $$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{a^2 \sin^2\theta+b^2 \cos^2\theta}$$

So I solved the indefinite integral first (by substitution):
$$\int\frac{d \theta}{a^2 \sin^2\theta+b^2 \cos^2\theta}=\frac{1}{b^2}\int\frac{d \theta}{\cos^2\theta \left(\frac{a^2}{b^2} \tan^2\theta+1 \right)} =\left[u=\frac{a}{b}\tan\theta, du=\frac{a}{b\cos^2\theta} d\theta \right ]\\=\frac{1}{b^2}\int\frac{b}{a\left(u^2+1 \right)}du=\frac{1}{ab}\int\frac{du}{u^2+1}=\frac{1}{ab} \arctan \left(\frac{a}{b}\tan\theta \right )+C$$

Then:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{a^2 \sin^2\theta+b^2 \cos^2\theta}=\frac{1}{ab} \arctan \left(\frac{a}{b}\tan (2\pi) \right )-\frac{1}{ab} \arctan \left(\frac{a}{b}\tan 0 \right )=0$$

Which is incorrect (the answer should be $2\pi/ab$ for $a>0,b>0$).

On the one hand, the substitution is correct, as well as the indefinite integral itself (according to Wolfram it is indeed $\frac{1}{ab} \arctan \left(\frac{a}{b}\tan\theta \right )$  ), but on the other hand I can see that had I put the limits during the substitution I'd get $\int\limits_{0}^{0} \dots = 0$ because for $\theta = 0 \to u=0$ and for $\theta = 2\pi \to u=0$.

Why is there a problem and how can I get the correct answer?

**Edit**: Here is Wolfram's answer:
[image]

Wolfram is correct because $$\frac{a^2 b^2}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{a^2 \sin^2\theta+b^2 \cos^2\theta}$$ is the area of an ellipse (defined by $x=a\cos t , y=b\sin t$), that is $$\frac{a^2 b^2}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d \theta}{a^2 \sin^2\theta+b^2 \cos^2\theta}=\pi ab$$

Comment: Hint: use $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$ to simplify the formula.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{ab}\arctan(\frac{a\tan(x)}{{b}})|_0^{2\pi}$

Comment: Isn't the answer $0$?

Comment: @user90369 - did you read my question?

Comment: @StubbornAtom - no. As I already said it should be $2\pi / ab$ - according to Wolfram and also because that integral times $a^2 b^2 / 2$ should give the area of an ellipse.

Comment: Note that the periodicity of $\tan$ is not $2\pi$ but $\pi$.

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170885)

Comment: This integral was also discussed at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518173/).

Comment: Apparently this question has been asked here many times before. Also check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/597152/321264) answer out for a similar question.

Comment: Sorry, I had no time.  - Of course you cannot jump over undefined points. You can distinguish between $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$, $[\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}]$, $[\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi]$ and to add the integrals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a^{2}\cos^2t+b^{2}\sin^{2}t}dt$, by deformation theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518173/calculate-the-integral-int-02-pi-frac1a2-cos2tb2-sin2tdt)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The substitution is incorrect : the tangent is not bijective on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. First, you need to restrict yourself to an interval on which the tangent behaves better. Using the $\pi$-periodicity of the function you want to integrate, you can show that:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{a \sin^2 (\theta)+b \cos^2 (\theta)} d \theta = 2 \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{a \sin^2 (\theta)+b \cos^2 (\theta)} d \theta,$$

and go from there.

Note that this is a good warning about using Wolfram (or any formal computation system) : the formula for the indefinite integral is good, but it holds only on each interval $(k\pi -\pi/2, k\pi+\pi/2)$, which the program does not tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b>0, $ by symmetry,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{d \theta}{a^{2} \sin ^{2} \theta+b^{2} \cos ^{2} \theta} &=4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d \theta}{a^{2} \sin ^{2} \theta+b^{2} \cos ^{2} \theta} \\
&=4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec ^{2} \theta d \theta}{a^{2} \tan ^{2} \theta+b^{2}} \\
&=4 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d t}{a^{2} t+b^{2}} \\
&=\frac{4}{a b}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a t}{b}\right)\right]_{0}^{\infty} \\
&=\frac{2 \pi}{a b} 
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

A slick way to compute this considers the closed loop $\gamma(t) = a\sin t + i b\cos t$ given by the ellipse and traversed clockwise. Then

$$\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{dw}w = -1$$

independently of $a$ and $b$ (this is computing the number of turns the ellipse makes around $w=0$, which is $-1$). On the other hand, computing the line integral explicitly gives

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi }\frac{\overline{\gamma(t)}}{|\gamma(t)|^2} \gamma'(t)dt &=  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi }\frac{a\sin t - i b\cos t}{a^2\sin^2 t + b^2\cos^2 t} (a\cos t - i b\sin t)dt \\
&=  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi }\frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos t\sin t-iab }{a^2\sin^2 t + b^2\cos^2 t} dt \\
\end{align}

The real part of this integral is
$$ -\frac{ab}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi }\frac{dt}{a^2\sin^2 t + b^2\cos^2 t} $$

which gives your result (and the imaginary part is of course zero).

Answer (score -1):

You have everything right up to 
$$
\frac{1}{ab}\arctan(\frac{a}{b}\tan(2\pi))-\frac{1}{ab}\arctan(\frac{a}{b}\tan(0))
$$
 Now $\frac{1}{ab}\arctan(\frac{a}{b}\tan(2\pi))$ is $2\pi$ because the $\arctan$ and the $\tan$ are inverse functions.

So we get
$$
\frac{1}{ab}\arctan(\frac{a}{b}\tan(2\pi))-\frac{1}{ab}\arctan(\frac{a}{b}\tan(0))=\frac{1}{ab}2\pi-0
$$
or
$$
\frac{2\pi}{ab}
$$

Comment: There's $a/b$ inside $\arctan$. If it was $\arctan (\tan 2\pi)$ I could understand.

Comment: $\tan (2\pi)=0$

Comment: yes you are right I'm sorry

Comment: You should delete this answer or else you might get downvoted.