# figure out $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{ab}{a^2\cos^2 t+b^2\sin^2 t}\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{ab}{a^2\cos^2 t+b^2\sin^2 t}\,dt$$
We are learning complex analysis... And an exercise is to verify $\int_{\gamma}z^{-1}dz=2\pi i$ where $\gamma(t)=a\cos t+i b\sin t$. I do some algebra and is stuck on the integral above.. I know we can use residue theorem to easily get the answer. I was wondering is any way in real analysis to figure this out?

Comment: Duplicate${}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311023/showing-int-02-pi-fracdta2-cos2-t-b2-sin2-t-frac2-pi/1311085#1311085), I used contour integration along with notes on other approaches to find the value of the integral of interest.

Here, the OP requested a way forward using real analysis only.  To that end, we proceed with a ...

**HINT:**

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{ab}{a^2\cos^2 t+b^2\sin^2 t}\,dt&=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{(b/a)\,\sec^2 t}{1+(b/a)^2\tan^2 t}\,dt
\end{align}$$

Now substitute $u=(b/a)\tan t$, with $du=(b/a)\sec^2 t\,dt$.

Comment: thank you!  Relations among trigonometric things is always interesting!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.